# Python: Communicate between two files

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a defined function in one program:

```
def start():
QuadraticButton = Button(left_frame, text = "Quadratic Equation Solver", command = calculateQuad)
QuadraticButton.pack()
```

and then in a separate script I have the "calculate quad" function defined. How can I link these two together, so when that button is pressed, the calculate quad function is called, from that separate file?

Comment: Start by reading any basic python tutorial about the import statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

include my_utils

```
def start():

    from .utils import calculateQuad

    QuadraticButton = Button(left_frame, text = "Quadratic Equation Solver", command = calculateQuad)
    QuadraticButton.pack()
```